# Search result is empty

Tags: commerce, search

When I do a search, I got an empty result even though the result shouldn't be null.
I even get a null result if I don't filter anything. However fulltext search works, only facets corresponding to a field seems to not work.

I copied a production database to a test server. Everything works fine on production, but I can make the test copy works.

I've seen there is some issue with facets if the user doesn't have the permission to create temporary table. I checked that, and I think I have the permission.

Any idea ? (I use drupal commerce)

Comment: Well, I think the obvious issue is that there is something different between production and testing ... it's likely the index server (I assume it's search api and/or solr powered faceting) is not available. Are you seeing index errors? What are you using to index your data? Have you tried flushing the index on the non-production server?

Comment: I've cleared the index, rebuilt it, the index tables are correct, but that doesn't seem to be enough. I'm using the basic sql backeng.

Comment: Would need a full export of the view + search api setup to debug. You're right, if all is perfect, it should work. It's even more mysterious that it works in one environment, but not the other. Leads me to think the issue is outside of Drupal. Perhaps an older MySQL or too limited of a setup. Do you see any errors in your logs that would help you point to a problem?

Comment: I'm using docker (one container for apache and one for mysql and there are exactly the same between the two environment). I'm happy to add some trace and do some debugging but I don't how where to start

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to different behavior between mysql 5.6 and 5.7. I thought I had the same environment between production and test but I was wrong. I use a docker image for mysql but didn't specify a version so I ended up with two different versions on the two systems, even though the provisioning looked the same.